# Extracting all the tags from xml with xpath

Tags: java, xpath

I need to extract all the values from the tag field with attribute name=body.
i used this xpath but it is returning only the first value

```
//example/test/field[@name='body']/text()

Example XML
        <example>
          <test>
            <field name="body">Example text</field>
            <field name="body">Example text1</field>
          </test>
        <example>
```

Comment: What do you want the XPath expression to return? A set of strings? Or a single long string? The former is not possible, the latter is not possible with a single expression in XPath 1.0. Which XPath version do you have available?

Comment: Are you sure it is returning a single value? Because every online xpath tester confirms that both values are returned. (Note: fix closing tag in your xml)

Comment: I stand corrected, Max Yakimets is right. Your xpath selects both texts well. How do you test your XPath? In xmlstarlet, the command `xml sel -t -v //example/test/field[@name='body']/text() test.xml` returns both texts.

Comment: If you have XPath 2.0 available, you can do `string-join(//example/test/field[@name='body']/text())` to join all the strings together.

Comment: The XPath expression you give returns a set of text nodes. How an environment deals with such sets is environment-specific; some take the first node only, when they are expecting a single node or string.  Yours seems to be one such environment.  But how to make it behave different is a question about your Java library, not about XPath.

Answer (score 0):

**For the provided XML document (all wanted elements are siblings and there are no other siblings elements, this XPath expression produces the wanted result:**

```
string(normalize-space(/*/test[not(*[not(@name='body')])]))
```